# calling asyncwait from a callback

Tags: javascript, node.js, callback, async-await, promise

I have a nodejs library written using the [async/await](https://github.com/yortus/asyncawait) module. I try to consume it from a library which uses regular callbacks. Here is a sample code:

```
var async = require('asyncawait/async');
var await = require('asyncawait/await');
var Promise = require('bluebird');

var foo = async (function() {
    var resultA = await (Promise.promisify(bar));
    return 111;
})

function bar(callback) {
  setTimeout(callback, 2000)
}

function moo() {
  var f = async.cps(foo)

  f(function(err, res) {
    console.log(res)
  })

}

moo()
```

I expected console.log to print 111 but instead it prints:

```
{ _bitField: 0,
  _fulfillmentHandler0: undefined,
  _rejectionHandler0: undefined,
  _progressHandler0: undefined,
  _promise0: undefined,
  _receiver0: undefined,
  _settledValue: undefined }
```

btw if I inline the foo implementation in the "async.cps" line it works (but this is not an option since its an external library).

Any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've looked at the library your using, and by the look of it (there isn't much, and certainly no working samples), you're not using it correctly.

`async(fn)` will return a function that accepts some input values and upon execution will return a promise (Probably [standard Promises/A+](https://promisesaplus.com/)). Inside, it will call `fn` with the input parameters, and will resolve the returned promise when `fn` has returned.

`async.cps(...)` will return a function that accepts some input values *and* a node style callback function (`function (err, res)`) and upon execution will return a void (`undefined`). Inside, it will call `fn` with the input parameters, and will call the callback function when `fn` has returned with the appropriate values.

what your code does is create a function with `async(fn)`, then pass this function to `async.cps(..)` as if you called `async.cps(async(fn))`, but that doesn't make any sense.

What you could do if you wanted to "convert" a promise to a node style callback function (unpromisifying!) using this library is this:

```
function moo() {
  var f = async.cps(function() {
    return await (foo())
  })

  f(function(err, res) {
    console.log(res)
  })
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You double-asynced the `foo` function. Here are your options, depending on whether you can modify the declaration of `foo` or not:

Leave `foo` async, and create a function `f` that accepts a node-style callback using `cps`:

```
var async = require('asyncawait/async');
var await = require('asyncawait/await');
var Promise = require('bluebird');

var foo = async(function() {
    var resultA = await (Promise.promisify(bar));
    return 111;
});

function bar(callback) {
  setTimeout(callback, 1000);
}

function moo() {
  var f = async.cps(function() {
    return await(foo());
  });
  f(function(err, res) {
    console.log(res);
  });
}

moo();
```

Leave `foo` async, and use an async `moo`:

```
var async = require('asyncawait/async');
var await = require('asyncawait/await');
var Promise = require('bluebird');

var foo = async(function() {
    var resultA = await (Promise.promisify(bar));
    return 111;
});

function bar(callback) {
  setTimeout(callback, 1000);
}

var moo = async(function() {
  try {
    var res = await(foo());
    console.log(res);
  } catch (err) {
  }
});    

moo();
```

Make `foo` already `cps` at the declaration:

```
var async = require('asyncawait/async');
var await = require('asyncawait/await');
var Promise = require('bluebird');

var foo = async.cps(function() {
    var resultA = await (Promise.promisify(bar));
    return 111;
});

function bar(callback) {
  setTimeout(callback, 1000);
}

function moo() {
  foo(function(err, res) {
    console.log(res);
  });
}

moo();
```